# $\forall m\geq 2, \exists n, m|(n^2+3)(n^2-13)(n^2+39)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, contest-math, divisibility

> **Problem.** Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, defined by: $a_n=(n^2+3)(n^2-13)(n^2+39), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Show that for any natural number $m \geq 2$, there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $m|a_n$.

This problem was proposed a long time ago for an JBMO selection, but unfortunately I don't have neither the exact source nor the official solution. Therefore, I have come up with my own.

**Please check these arguments** (maybe with all the details, if possible), and any suggestions, improvements, or even shorter, ellegant solutions are more than welcome. Thank you for your time and effort!

---

Before solving, first some additional considerations about [quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue):

> **Proposition.**
> a) Let $p$ be a prime natural number and $a\in \mathbb{Z}, p\nmid a$. Then $a$ is quadratic remainder modulo $p$ iff $a$ is quadratic residue modulo $p^k$, for any natural number $k\geq 1$.
> b) Let $a$ be an odd integer, and $k\geq 3$ be a fixed natural number. Then $a$ is quadratic residue modulo $2^k$ iff $a\equiv 1$ (mod $8$).

*Proof*:
$a)$ As the converse is obvious, it remains to show the direct implication, by induction over $k\geq 1$. Let $n_1\in \mathbb{N}$, for which $p^1|n_1^2-a$, this is the verification step. Suppose that for a certain $k\geq 1$ we have constructed $n_k\in \mathbb{N}$, for which $p^k|n_k^2-a$, and we want to find a $n_{k+1 }\in \mathbb{N}$, for which $p^{k+1}|n_{k+1}^2-a$. For this, we will look for $\lambda \in \mathbb{N}$, with $n_{k+1}=n_{k}+\lambda p^k$. So:
$$p^{k+1}|n_{k+1}^2-a \Leftrightarrow p^{k+1}|n_k^2-a+\lambda^2p^{2k}+2\lambda n_kp^k \Leftrightarrow p|x_k+2\lambda n_k, \tag{1}$$
where $x_k:=(n_k^2-a)/p^k \in \mathbb{Z}$. If somehow $p|n_k$, from $p|p^k|n_k^2-a$ would result $p|a$, contradiction with the hypothesis! So $p\nmid n_k, p\nmid 2 \Rightarrow p\nmid 2n_k$. Thus:
$$(1) \Leftrightarrow (2n_k)\lambda \equiv -x_k (\text{mod p}) \Leftrightarrow \lambda \equiv -x_k(2n_k)^{-1} (\text{mod p}). \tag{2}$$
We choose $\lambda\in\mathbb{N}$, which verifies the condition from $(2)$, and the induction is complete.

$b)$ ($\Rightarrow$) If $a$ is quadratic residue modulo $n$, then it is quadratic residue modulo any divisor of $n$. Here, $a$ will become a quadratic residue modulo $2^3=8$. As $a$ is odd, and the quadratic residues modulo $8$ are $0,1,4$, it follows that $a\equiv 1$ (mod $8$).
($\Leftarrow$) Let $a\equiv 1$ (mod $8$), then, as above, $a$ is quadratic residue modulo $8$. We will show (similar to point $a)$ by induction after $k\geq 3$ that $a$ is quadratic residue modulo $2^k$, for any such $k$. The verification step is already done, and $n_1\in \mathbb{N}$ appears, for which $2^3|n_1^2-a$. Suppose that for a certain $k\geq 3$ we have constructed $n_k\in \mathbb{N}$, for which $2^k|n_k^2-a$, and we want to find a $n_{k+1} \in \mathbb{N}$, for which $2^{k+1}|n_{k+1}^2-a$. For this, we will look for $\lambda \in \mathbb{N}$, with $n_{k+1}=n_{k}+\lambda 2^{k-1}$ ($2^k$ is not enough, since $2$ is non-invertible modulo $p=2$). So:
$$2^{k+1}|n_{k+1}^2-a \Leftrightarrow 2^{k+1}|n_k^2-a+\lambda^2p^{2k-2}+\lambda n_k2^k \Leftrightarrow 2|x_k+\lambda n_k, \tag{3}$$
where $x_k:=(n_k^2-a)/2^k \in \mathbb{Z}$. If somehow $2|n_k$, from $2|2^k|n_k^2-a$ would result $2|a$, contradiction with the fact that $a$ is odd! So $2\nmid n_k$, and then:
$$(3) \Leftrightarrow n_k\lambda \equiv -x_k (\text{mod 2}) \Leftrightarrow \lambda \equiv -x_k (\text{mod 2}). \tag{4}$$
We choose $\lambda\in \{0,1\}$, which verifies the condition from $(4)$, and the induction is complete. $\Box$

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> **Problem.** Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, defined by: $a_n=(n^2+3)(n^2-13)(n^2+39), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Show that for any natural number $m \geq 2$, there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $m|a_n$.

We will show the following intermediate result: if $m_1, m_2 \geq 2$ are two coprime natural numbers, with $m_1|a_i, m_2|a_j$, for some $i,j \in \mathbb{N }$, then $m_1m_2|a_k$ for a certain $k$ natural number.

We can assume, without loss of generality, that $i\geq j$. It is clear that $m_1|a_{i+xm_1}, m_2|a_{j+ym_2}$, for any $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$. As $(m_1, m_2)=1$, there exists $r\in \mathbb{N}$, for which $m_1r \equiv 1$ (mod $m_2$) (modular inverse). It is enough to show that the equation $i+xm_1=j+ym_2$ has solutions in $x,y$, in which case we will take $k:=i+xm_1$. Indeed, the equation becomes:
$i-j+xm_1 \equiv 0$ (mod $m_2$) $\Leftrightarrow x\equiv (j-i)r $ (mod $m_2$). We choose an $x\in \mathbb{N}$ with this property, then $y=\frac{i-j+xm_1}{m_2}\in \mathbb{N}$, hence the conclusion.

Due to the above and prime factorization, it remains to prove for $m=p^k$, i.e. for powers of prime numbers. To solve the problem, it is enough to show that for such $m$, at least one of $-3,13,-39$, is a quadratic remainder modulo $m$ (in which case there is a natural $n$, with $ p^k$ divides $n^2+3$ or $n^2-13$ or $n^2+39$, so $p^k|a_n$).

We show that the statement holds for $k=1$, first. We have that: $a_1=-1920, a_6=67275$, so $2|a_1, 3|a_1, 13|a_6$. Let from now $p\neq 2,3,13$, and assume by absurdity that $p\nmid a_n, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. This means that $p \nmid n^2+3, n^2-13, n^2+39, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, that is:
$$\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{13}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-39}{p}\right)=- 1 \Rightarrow \left(\frac{-39}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)\left(\frac{13}{p}\right)=(-1)(-1)=1,$$
contradiction. So, $p|a_n$, for a certain natural number $n$.

Thus, we deduce that, for any prime number $p\neq 2,3,13$, at least one of $-3,13,-39$, is quadratic remainder modulo $p$. Also, $\left(\frac{13}{3}\right)=\left(\frac{-3}{13}\right)=1.$ Therefore, for any prime number $p\neq 2 ,3,13$, at least one of $-3,13,-39$, is quadratic remainder modulo $p$. According to point $a)$ of the Proposition, at least one of $-3,13,-39$, is quadratic remainder modulo $p^k$, for any $k\geq 1$ natural number, hence the conclusion of the problem.

We are left with the case $p=2$. Of course, it suffices to prove for $2^k, k\geq 3$. We have that $-39\equiv 1$ (mod $8$), and according to point $b)$ of the Proposition, $-39$ becomes a quadratic remainder modulo $2^k$, for any $k\geq 3$, hence the conclusion.

---

**Generalization.** We consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ of integers, defined by: $x_n=(n^2-a)(n^2-b)(n^2-ab), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$ For what unassociated odd primes $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, it is true (with the same proof as above) that: for any $m \geq 2$ natural number, there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m|x_n$?

**Solution:** The previous statement holds for $a=-3, b=13$. The intermediate result concerning the reduction to powers of prime numbers could be done without regard to $a,b$ (all that mattered was the polynomial form of $x_n$ as a function of $n$). Then, it sufficed to show that for each $m=p^k$, one of $a,b$ or $ab$ is quadratic remainder modulo $m$.

For $k=1$, $p\neq 2,a,b$, the argument with the Legendre symbol is valid, $a|x_{|a|}, b|x_{|b|}, 2|x_1$. So we solved for $p^k$, with $p\neq 2,a,b$.

The argument for $2^k$ works if $a,b$ or $ab$ is congruent to $1$, modulo $8$. Also, for $a^k$, we need $b$ to be the quadratic residue modulo $a$, analogously, for $b^k$, $a$ to be the quadratic residue modulo $b$.

In conclusion, the proposed solution is essentially the same, for non-associated odd primes $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, which simultaneously checks the conditions:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
a \equiv 1 (\text{mod 8}) \lor b \equiv 1 (\text{mod 8}) \lor ab \equiv 1 (\text{mod 8})\\
\left(\frac{a}{|b|}\right)=\left(\frac{b}{|a|}\right)=1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}